# Applescript for auto scrolling in Font Book. I could use some expert guidance

Tags: scroll, fonts, applescript

As a graphic designer, I am constantly having to identify which fonts to use in a document or match a font. Currently I have over 5000 different fonts.  I don't keep all 5000 installed on my system. However, I usually do have to scroll through custom collections of 1000 fonts or more using the down arrow key.  Sometimes the whole process takes me the better part of an hour

I created a script for auto scrolling in Font Book and saved it as an application named “FontBook_Auto_Scroll.app”.  Basically it opens a dialog window giving me three options. If I select “arrow down”, it brings Font Book to the front and pushes the arrow down key 35 times in increments of half a second.

[image]

[image]

Then the dialogue window opens again.  If I select “arrow up”, it brings Font Book to the front and pushes the arrow up key 7 times, etc. But here is the problem.  If in the process of “scrolling down”, I see the font I want to use and it happens to appear as the second font in the “scrolling down” cycle, I would prefer not to have to wait until the 35 arrow key down entries are completed.

I'm still playing around with this script and making revisions as I continue reading AppleScript help documents.  This is what I have so far.

```
property selectedFontFamily : missing value

tell application "Font Book"
    activate
    delay 5
    try
        set (selected collections) to font domain "AllFonts"
    on error errMsg number errNum
        set (selected collections) to font domain "AllFonts"
    end try
    try
        set (selected font families) to font family 1
    on error errMsg number errNum
        set (selected font families) to font family 1
    end try
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 2 times
        key code 48
    end repeat
end tell
delay 1
repeat 40 times
    activate
    display dialog "Font Book Scrolling" buttons {"Arrow Down", "Arrow Up", "Cancel"} default button 1 giving up after 7
    set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
    if the button_pressed is "" then
        tell application "Font Book"
            activate
            delay 1
            set (selected collections) to font domain "AllFonts"
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
            delay 1
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            delay 3
            repeat 55 times
                delay 0.6
                key code 125
            end repeat
            delay 1
        end tell
        tell application "Font Book"
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
        end tell
    else if the button_pressed is "Arrow Down" then
        tell application "Font Book"
            activate
            set (selected collections) to font domain "AllFonts"
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            delay 3
            repeat 55 times
                delay 0.6
                key code 125
            end repeat
            delay 1
        end tell
        tell application "Font Book"
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
        end tell
    else if the button_pressed is "Arrow Up" then
        tell application "Font Book"
            activate
            set (selected collections) to font domain "AllFonts"
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            delay 1
            repeat 15 times
                delay 0.7
                key code 126
            end repeat
            delay 1
        end tell
        tell application "Font Book"
            set selectedFontFamily to (selected font families)
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 37 using {command down, option down}
            end tell
        end tell
    else if the button_pressed is "Cancel" then
        tell application "Font Book"
            quit
        end tell
        return
    end if
end repeat
quit
end

on quit
    tell application "Font Book"
        quit
    end tell
    continue quit -- allows the script to quit
end quit
```

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to programmatically mathematically calculate where based on the properties of the UI Elements to click, where to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that once an AppleScript application starts running its *script*, sans coded exit points, the only way to get out of a loop is to force quit the application.

Because one may have more then one AppleScript application running at a time **and** the executable's name, regardless of what one named the application, is `applet`, you don't want to use a command like `do shell script "kill -9 $(pgrep applet)"`, as it will kill all running AppleScript applications.

I'd have second AppleScript application handy, e.g. "Terminate - FontBook_Auto_Scroll.app", in the Dock for quick access, to isolate the `PID` of the *target* AppleScript application, using the following *command* syntax:

```
do shell script "kill -9 $(ps -x | awk '/[N]ame.app/{print $1}'); exit 0"
```

In the case of your "FontBook_Auto_Scroll.app", the *command* would be:

```
do shell script "kill -9  $(ps -x | awk '/[F]ontBook_Auto_Scroll.app/{print $1}'); exit 0"
```

- The first character of the application's name is in square braces so as not to confuse the `PID` returned of the `awk` query that has the target AppleScript application's name in it.
- The `; exit 0` it there so if you accidentally run the AppleScript application that terminates the target AppleScript application when it's not running, it does not error out.

Then when you want to stop the scrolling, use the "Terminate - FontBook_Auto_Scroll.app" AppleScript application to terminate the "FontBook_Auto_Scroll.app" AppleScript application.

BTW Looking at the coding of your AppleScript application, the issue you're going to run into is while it's in the loop, if you set focus elsewhere, the `key code` events are going to go to whatever has focus.

Update:

Here is some example *code*, using [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/), to programmatically mathematically calculate, based on the properties of the UI Elements, where to click.

Tested under macOS 10.12.5, this *code* will click the *All Fonts collection*, then the *first Font* in that *collection*.

Note: Change the *value* of the `cliclick` *variable* based on where it's located on your system.

```
set cliclick to POSIX path of (path to home folder as string) & "bin/cliclick"

tell application "Font Book"
    activate
    -- delay 1
    tell application "System Events"

        set position of window 1 of application process "Font Book" to {0, 22}
        set size of window 1 of application process "Font Book" to {800, 622}

        set theFontBookAllFontsProperties to ¬
            get properties ¬
                of static text 1 ¬
                of UI element 1 ¬
                of row 2 ¬
                of outline 1 ¬
                of scroll area 1 ¬
                of splitter group 1 ¬
                of window 1 ¬
                of application process "Font Book"

        set theFontBookAllFontsPosition to position in theFontBookAllFontsProperties
        set theFontBookAllFontsSize to size in theFontBookAllFontsProperties
        set theXpos to (item 1 of theFontBookAllFontsPosition) + (item 1 of theFontBookAllFontsSize) / 2 as integer
        set theYpos to (item 2 of theFontBookAllFontsPosition) + (item 2 of theFontBookAllFontsSize) / 2 as integer

        tell current application
            -- delay 0.25
            do shell script cliclick & " c:" & theXpos & "," & theYpos
        end tell

        set theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsProperties to ¬
            get properties ¬
                of static text 1 ¬
                of UI element 1 ¬
                of row 1 ¬
                of outline 1 ¬
                of scroll area 2 ¬
                of splitter group 1 ¬
                of window 1 ¬
                of application process "Font Book"

        set theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsPosition to position in theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsProperties
        set theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsSize to size in theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsProperties
        set theXpos to (item 1 of theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsPosition) + (item 1 of theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsSize) / 2 as integer
        set theYpos to (item 2 of theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsPosition) + (item 2 of theFontBookAllFontsFirstFontsSize) / 2 as integer

        tell current application
            -- delay 0.25
            do shell script cliclick & " c:" & theXpos & "," & theYpos
        end tell

    end tell
end tell
```

Note: The `delay` *commands* may or may not be necessary and or may or may not need to have the *value* of the delay modified. Uncomment and set as appropriate to the needs.

Comment: Yes I am painfully aware of the Loop issue effecting anything that has focus.  Fontbook Is extremely stubborn.  Quickly before the loop kicks in, I have to manually select "All Fonts" Then the first font in the list.  Otherwise the script takes control over what is focused at that moment.  Every effort I have made to script the action of selecting the item "All Fonts" then the first font, have failed

Comment: @wch1zpink, When I run an AppleScript app on an application that will not click what I want where I want, I use [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) to do the clicking. I set the bounds of the window to where I want it and then get the cords of where I want to click, then code it to programmatic click where I want it to click. Or I go the extra mile and actually programmatically mathematically calculate where based on the properties of the UI Elements I want to click and it clicks there.

Comment: @wch1zpink, I've found that its quite reliable to do it either way. The caveat of course is the target app must have focus, but that's not a big deal because, when I'm going to use this method, I'm single tasking at that moment to allow the processing to do as programmed.  BTW I use cliclick over MouseTools because I find it to work better then MouseTools does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with cliclick.  I just downloaded it now and will give it a test run shortly.

Comment: updated the code... selecting the font family and font collections works now